# close established off state tcp connections

Tags: node.js, tcp

When I run the following command

netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

it gives the out as following:

```
 1 established
  1 Foreign
  6 LISTEN
 51 TIME_WAIT
789 ESTABLISHED
```

I know that there should be a maximum 50 tcp connections but it shows 789. How to handle this?
I have added the image which gives a better description of my problem.

[image]

Comment: Look at those connections and see where they are connector from/to and what ports they are using.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have added a screenshot.. is there any clean way to handle those kind of connections ?

Comment: Those are all distinct outside machines that have connected to a service you are running on port 10,000.

Comment: yes they are. but there should be atmost 50 connections. Not more then 50 connections are made at a time. do this have anything to do with mobile networks as the tcp connections are made from mobile devices.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to implement dead client detection? What protocol are you using? Websocket?

Comment: node's net module(tcp connections).

Comment: by dead client detection do you mean half dropped connections if not can you give some clue to implement that.

Comment: What protocol are you using over TCP? How does it detect dead clients? (By dead clients, I mean a client that just disappears without tearing down the TCP connection.)

Comment: I am using no protocol over tcp(raw tcp server ).  yes the dead connection are quite possible in my case. how to handle these connections ?

Comment: i have id for each device, when the device is connecting  it will send the id first. I store all socket objects mapped to their device ids. Now if I receive a new connection with same id then i am destroying the previous socket mapped with that id.

Comment: What if the device never sent an ID? How do you detect a dead client that dies before it sends its ID? Does this protocol have a written specification? If so, can we see it? Likely either you implemented it incorrectly or the specification is defective in some way.

Comment: I would advise you to go back over the specification carefully to ensure its dead client detection scheme is solid and that you understand it thoroughly. Then go back over the code to ensure it implements the protocol's dead client detection correctly in all cases. If solid dead client detection is either not specified or not implemented, you should expect dead clients to accumulate over time.